# Checking for illegal/duplicate windows file names in NTFS

Tags: dual-boot, ntfs, filename

Is there a command line tool for checking if a file name is illegal on windows? Similarly, is there a command line tool for checking if file names will clash when case insensitive? I know how to check long paths using `find` so that's fine. I store all my documents on an NTFS partition for dual boot with windows, and I have a rather bad habit of putting colons in file names when representing times.

I am aware there is a mount option for this, but I don't think that it will solve my problem.

Comment: "if a file name is illegal on windows" ehm we do not (need to) know what legal is on windows as we support Ubuntu. If you need to find files bases on specific chars you will need to list those. On Linux you can use any character, even enters :)

Comment: I'm asking for an existing program, not for a regex expression to be used in `find`, so I don't think that matters to much.